# Creating a load event for text label in windows application c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# programming language. I am trying to create a windows form application in c# .net using VS 2012. I have created a text label and I want to display a text when the application is loaded. I see only click event rather than load event. would anyone please suggest what to do? (I am expecting something like "lblText_Load")
[image]

Comment: Why not just set the desired text in the designer?

Comment: Try doing this on `Form Load()` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label does not have an event for loaded. You can either use the Form's Load event, or the OnShown event.

I suggest using the OnShown event because this will be triggered after the form is loaded and displayed. The OnLoad event for the form occurs when it begins to load not after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form's Load event. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional information.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    lblText.Text = "w00t \o/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the load event of the form you can do what you want.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    lblText.Text = "Evaluation Tool";
}
```

Forms have lots of events you can use (Load, Activated, Shown , etc.)